# How to prevent file redirection to VirtualStore for read/write files?

Tags: windows-7, c#-2.0, virtualstore

I am using C# with .net 2.0

I am saving my program data in a file under: `C:\ProgramData\MyProgramName\fileName.xml`

After installing and running my application one time I uninstalled it (during uninstallation I'm removing all the files from "program data") and then I reinstall the application, and ran it.

The strange thing is that my application started as if the files in program data existed - means, I had old data in my app even though the data file was deleted.

When running:

```
File.Exists("C:\ProgramData\MyProgramName\fileName.xml")
```

I got "true" even though I knew for sure that the file does not exist.

The thing became stranger when I ran the application as admin and then the file didn't exist.

After a research, I found out that when running my application with no admin privileges instead of getting:

```
C:\ProgramData\MyProgramName\fileName.xml
```

I get

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ProgramData\MyProgramName\fileName.xml
```

and indeed there was a file that existed from the previous installation (that I obviously didn't delete, because I didn't know it existed).

---

So just guide me how could I stop this when apps running with no admin right.

I do not want to create any file automatically in VirtualStore folder. Please discuss all the possible ways to stop this.

Comment: This question lead me in the right direction. Logically, if an application needs administrative access to write to these system folders; request that your app run in admin mode. From my experience with Windows this can be done programatically. I think this is a good move of Microsoft and it is not nearly as crippling as Android file system restrictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ask yourself, do this need to be globally saved for all users?

If it doesn't have to be, save the file in Application Data instead, you can get the path with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`, it should always reliably expand to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\`. Do note that this path is unique for each user though.

If you have to, you're out of luck. There is no reliable way to store application data for all users without admin rights (or UAC) on any Windows post-XP that's not extremely hacky, like storing your data in the Public user (which may or may not be possible, I can't check right now).

Comment: file redirection to VirtualStore only happen in win7 not in xp. i always want to create file from where our application is running. file is global for all user.so just guide me how could i stop this.

Comment: @Thomas that's because of the security improvements in Vista and higher. On Windows XP all administrator accounts run all applications as administrator and folder restrictions are quite bad. My point is that VirtualStore is a security feature which can't be worked around without changing the directory. You could try writing the settings to the Public profile's Application Data folder though, as doing so would let all accounts access it.

Comment: i am not writing anything in virtual store folder.i am writing/reading file from my application but win7 copy that file to virtual store\... and force my apps to read the file from there.ca u plzz tell me how could i run my apps with admin right automatically when develop with VS2005. login user may be or may not be admin but my apps will act as admin. in VS2005 there is no way to add manifest file.so guide me how could i handle this situation. thanks

Comment: You have to manually add a manifest file, I believe the compiler will still include it. You could also switch to another, newer, IDE such as [Xamarin Studio (or MonoDevelop)](http://monodevelop.com/). It's free and really has only benefits.

Comment: See also the [accepted answer to *Privileges/owner issue when writing in C:\ProgramData*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107884/2932052) and the comments below for a deeper analysis of how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to solving this is to use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` location, but with some very important caveats & setup.

`CommonApplicationData` is

> The directory that serves as a common repository for
>   application-specific data that is used by all users.

This location is described further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501345/3195477) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8).

Important requirements and restrictions are given in another SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107884/3195477

which said in part:

> The recommended solution is for your installer to create a sub
>   directory of C:\ProgramData for your shared storage. And that sub
>   directory must be given a permissive ACL by the installation program.
>   That is what grants the desired access to all standard users.

Otherwise the program running with standard user permission will still not be all equally able to read/write files in that location for all users.

Answer (score -1):

I found a work around for this issue when transferring a very old win32 app to windows 7 & 10. The program wrote to a database on C:\Program Files... but the OS auto changed the path to virtual store. However the database was required globally. By changing compatablilty mode to Windows 95 or XP SP2 and always running as administrator the database was worked on directly in C:\Program Files\etc.

There are security implications for this and the box was removed from all networks and adapters disabled etc.

Comment: Changing compatibility mode to WIndows XP is not a good alternative.