# Where are Log Files Placed Typically?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

My app does not have admin rights.Where is the typical location where Log Files are placed? The app will be installed to `c:\programfiles\myapp`

Comment: What logger do you use?

Comment: @StepUp Nothing.. Just save the list of files that failed to process.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a Windows desktop application then you should look at the enumeration [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the logs in the `CommonApplicationData`

```
 // This should be the path to C:\ProgramData
 string commonDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

 // Now add your app name to the path above
 string myAppDataPath = Path.Combine(commonDataPath, "MyAppName");

 // Create the directory specific for your app (no error if it exists)
 Directory.CreateDirectory(myAppDataPath);

 // Prepare a log file with an embedded time stamp for today
 string logFile = "MyAppData" + DateTime.Today.Year + 
                                DataTime.Today.Month.ToString("D2") +
                                DataTime.Today.Day.ToString("D2") + ".LOG";

 // And finally here the name for your logging activities
 string fullLogFile = Path.Combine(myAppDataPath, logFile);
```

Be aware that according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107812/privileges-owner-issue-when-writing-in-c-programdata) only the user that creates this files could write there. Other users on the same machine no. However this could be changed using `ApplicationData` instead of `CommonApplicationData` but this also means that each user has its own log. If you want one store location for all of your users then it is up to you to create a specific folder and apply the permissions set required. Also if you want to show these files to your users then you could place them in its document folder using the enum `MyDocuments`.

Comment: Does `CommonApplicationData` ,require admin rights?

Comment: Somewhat see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107812/privileges-owner-issue-when-writing-in-c-programdata This means that the user that install the program could create and write there, other users on the same machine no. However this could be changed using ApplicationData instead of CommonApplicationData but this also means that each user has its own log. If you want one store location for all of your users then it is up to you to create a specific folder and apply the permissions set required

Comment: I just need to do this for the current user.Can i create a folder and write to my documents so that the user can read it whenever he/she wants easily.

Comment: Yes, if the requirement is to facilitate the reading of these files to your user, then the same Environment.SpecialFolder enum has an entry for MyDocuments

Comment: okay...  i hope i dont need any special rights for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try with [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)