# Specify Database path while creating database using EF Code First

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm  Creating Windows forms app using EF Code First. I want to save database in the local folder of project like app_data folder as we use to save in asp.net web forms. I think this makes deployment easier. How this can be done in Windows forms?

Answer (score 1):

set a string to Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData

string mAppDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

see also [What directories do the different Application SpecialFolders point to in WindowsXP and Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501167/what-directories-do-the-different-application-specialfolders-point-to-in-windows)